# Am I guaranteed to have the original stat as an option when recalibrating my gear?

Tags: the-division

Recalibrating gear can be an expensive ordeal, especially when you find an item you want to keep but just want to potentially improve one of its stats.

I rerolled a stat that I liked but it's on the lower end of the spectrum of possible percentages. I want to try rerolling it again to see if I can get a better version of the same skill, but I'm worried I might roll a completely different set of stats that I do not want.

**If I rerolled a stat on an item, will I always have that stat as an option? Or is it possible that I might roll all different stats?**

e.g.,

Suppose I had an item that I rolled Scavenging 40% (of 40-60%).  If I rerolled, am I guaranteed that I will see Scavenging (at any percentage) as an option?

Comment: In the particular case that I'm looking at, the item I'm recailbrating has only 2 out of 11 possible stats that I want. I already recalibrated 4 times just to get one of those. I don't want to lose that stat if I decided to try to improve that one, especially for one that I have a low probability of getting in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you re-calibrate gear, **the first option is always to retain your original bonus**; However, the bonus retains its original value. This is only useful in ensuring you do not loose the bonus, all together.

#### The Test

To confirm this, I did my own testing. I re-calibrated 10 different items, twice. I focused on the same set of possible bonuses, to make it easier to assess the numbers.

- Sticky Bomb explosion radius
- Mobile Cover damage resilience
- First Aid ally heal
- Smart Cover duration
- Pulse Critical Hit Damage bonus
- Ballistic Shield health
- Seeker Mine explosion radius
- Support Station healing speed
- Turret duration

#### The Results

I found that not only was the original bonus always an option, but it was always the first option, and always the exact same value.

Given only 20 re-calibrations were made, there is always the chance of getting lucky and always rolling the original bonus. However, the chances of the bonus also always rolling for the first option, and being of the exact same value, is very minimal.

#### Observations on upgrading the value of a bonus

I estimate that about 1 in very 5 re-calibrations gave the bonus as a second option. Given that you are trying to upgrade the value of the bonus, this is what you are trying to do. I also estimate that about half of these doubles also retained the same value, **so only 1 in 10 provided a chance to retain the bonus at a different value.**

This aspect would need to be explored further, across far more re-calibrations.

Comment: If instead of the performance stats, you re-rolled the firearms/stamina/electronics stat, the picture is even clearer: you get the original at the same value plus one each new values (total of four choices, of which the first is, as you say, the original at the same value).

Comment: Maybe I'm explaining it wrong, but they  always give you the choice of retaining the other.  So there's always four choices in the firearms/stamina/electronics slot.  Really, try it.  Caveat: I'm on XB1, so YMMV on other platforms.

Comment: I'm very confused.   Every single time I've rerolled one of the three-valued attribute booster (firearms, stamina, electronics), the result has been four choices:  the original one (of whichever kind it was) plus newly rolled values for the three.  You're sure we're both talking about firearms/stamina/electronics, not "damage to elites" or whatever, right?

Comment: @CPerkins, one last time with feeling, **all rolls are random**. You can roll two firearms, stamina and electronics (the most likely). You can roll two firearms and two electronics (unlikely). You can roll four firearms (very unlikely). **The rolls are completely random.** I would contest that you are just very (in)lucky, or simply havnt played with the mechanic all that much. I have personally had a "3 electronics, 1 firearm" roll on a major statistic.

Comment: I stopped trying to improve bonuses that I wanted to keep (just increase the number) after four times rolling the same value. I concluded as you did: you always get the original bonus at the original value. So I stopped trying to improve values. But, as you said you can get the same bonus twice, and I've had that happen finally, getting two Stamina and two Electronics. In your tests, did you determine if you start with bonus A with +X value, reroll it and choose a different bonus B, and reroll again . . . do you still get the original bonus A with +X, or does B now become the original?

Comment: @DavidHarkness, my tests did not extend that far, but there did not seem to be a pattern on the extra stats.